# MetaMask incorrectly flagged a website as phishing site

Tags: metamask

I am the product manager of Wincity, a French and legal company (we have everything to prove it).

I don't understand why, but MetaMask's anti-fishing feature sees us as a fishing website.

Which we are obviously not.

We have a mint today, so this may have dramatic consequences for our business.

Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Anti-phishing feature is based on user reports.

It's likely because fraudsters have reported your website just to annoy you or cause harm to you, and to undermine the integrity of MetaMask's antiphishing features.

The only way to fix the issue is to contact MetaMask antiphishing team and wait them to manually fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Do you know how we can accelerate the process? Our next mint is in 4 hours and the support is not reactive. This is really easy to check...

This can put our business in jeopardy...

Comment: No I don't know how to accelerate. My advise is not to plan your business around the fact that any spam tools flagging it can damage your business.